Can it be proven through unaided reason that God can't lie?
Rabbinic Judaism makes the rather blasphemous (and bizarre) claim that God lied to Abraham in Gn. 18:13/4.

"In one case we even find God twisting the truth in order to preserve amicable relations between Abraham and Sarah and to prevent Abraham’s feelings from being hurt. Upon overhearing the prediction that she was about to become pregnant, Sarah laughs, “Now that I am withered, am I to have enjoyment—with my husband so old?” (Gen. 18:12); God, however, quotes her in Abraham’s hearing as having said, “Shall I in truth bear a child, old as I am?” (Gen. 18:13), making no reference to Abraham’s inadequacy. This episode was used by the Sages of the Talmud as a proof-text showing that it is permitted to deviate from the strict line of truth in order to establish peace (BT Yeb. 65b; BT B.M. 87a)."


Yael Shemesh, Lies by Prophets and Other Lies in the Hebrew Bible, 2. Lies in the Bible  (paper|Bar-Ilan University), p. 4.


"I BEING OLD — Scripture [euphemism for God] in relating her words to her husband alters them for the sake of peace, for she had said (v. 12) 'my lord is old'" (Rashi on Gn. 18:13).


"Bar Kappara said: Peace [between spouses] is a great thing, as even Scripture [euphemism for God] spoke untruths [baddāʾîṯ] in order to establish peace between Abraham and Sarah" (Bereshit Rabbah 48:18).

The Bible does not make it clear in no uncertain terms that God did not, in fact, lie.  So, my question is can it be proven through unaided reason (that is, natural theology) that God can't lie? I need a detailed explanation that goes beyond "God is truth."

What presuppositions are you happy for the answer to start from?  Do you want the answer to show from reason alone: 1 There is a god; 2 The God of the Bible is God or 3 you cannot use the Bible until from reason uou have demonstrated that the Bible is from God. You haven't explained the premises and "facts" you are willing to accept as the basis for any answer.

Can you get us a source for that blasphemous and bizarre claim? I'd be able to answer more effectively if I could see it. I'll likely google it, but it should be linked here.

On second thought, I'll just edit it in for you. :) There you go

Numbers 23:19, Titus 1:2 and Hebrews 6:18 make it abundantly clear that God does not and can not lie. What further 'proof' is needed ?

@NigelJ If God commands a spirit to lie, is God the one lying? Just like if I hire a hitman, I'm guilty of murder?

@Wyrsa If men do not submit to God and believe in him, and he sends strong delusion to them (in demonic form) so that the wild nonsense coming out of their mouths identifies them as ungodly, and warns people away from them, what is wrong with that ?

@NigelJ If I hired/commanded a "bad person" to do something "evil" to someone else who is also "evil" with the intent of "warning others" I am righteous? After all, what is wrong with that?

@Wyrsa Yes, a 'hirer' (who is equal to the other two) would be errant. But He who creates all, for his Own Divine Purposes ? Not at all.

@NigelJ I think we need a longer form conversation to resolve this. It sounds like you are suggesting that God created something to "sin for Him" instead of Him. Which seems inaccurate. I think what you are trying to say is "God permitted a demon to afflict them" which of course is perfectly okay, as it was within their ability to resist the temptation of the demonic spirit.

@Wyrsa My meaning was the latter. The Creator has the right to achieve his own ends by using that which he has (already) created.

Nobody would disagree with the fact that reason can be twisted to infer that the truth is a lie.
Criminal courts are fully taken up with prosecution and defense arguments to reason their case is true, in order to show the other's to be untrue. Sometimes the truth is subtly twisted and justice is perverted. Humans are really active in that area.
In both such secular cases and the case in question here, ALL the relevant facts have to be marshaled and presented without bias. In the biblical text given, further facts about the original Hebrew wording must be known. If the Rabbinic Judaism party quoted here happened to have an agenda (an underlying motive) for claiming that God lied to Abram in Genesis 18:13-14, then their arguments would be suspect. Then, if further biblical evidence about the righteous judgments of God at all times could be presented, it may become clear that humans on earth, living long after the fact of that conversation between Abram and God, are in no position to jump to the conclusion that God can lie - claiming he has lied.
In the Rabbinic case cited, the idea that God will lie in order to maintain peaceful relations between a husband and his wife smacks of human reasoning, not God's. For sure, the Hebrew scriptures often expose the fact of marital strife, without any intervention on God's part to maintain marital harmony. Why would God lie just to prevent Abram's feelings being hurt? That says more about men's pride than it does about God's sacred word. Prideful human reason will never prove God to be a liar, no matter how 'unaided' reason is twisted.
The last word on this particular example (and all other matters) lies with God, on the Day of Resurrection and Judgment. Until then, humans are free to argue their heads off, if that's what they like to do. But, "Let God be found true, though every man a liar" (Romans 3:4) And he will.

The best way to explain this would probably be to read Aquinas' Summa on the various Divine Attributes, this would be questions 2-26 in the Prima Pars. Of note is question 16 article 5, on truth in God, specifically God as Truth, and you will need to take this a bit further and show how it is the case that Truth Itself cannot lie. To aid with this, I suggest also reading question 19 article 9, which will explain that God cannot will any evil. You can also take a look at the transcendental properties, which are Truth, Beauty, and Goodness, and perhaps show that, since Goodness and Truth must be identical, any lie is opposed to Goodness. Hence, to tell a lie would cause God to be not good, at least in some respect.
Lastly, in case anyone should doubt whether to tell a lie is always evil, one could use Aquinas' argument that lying is intrinsically evil, which would be found in the Secunda Secundae, question 110, article 3
A basic outline of the proof would be as follows

Truth is identical with Goodness
To will what is contrary to Goodness is sinful, and an imperfection
Since Truth and Goodness are identical, whatever is contrary to Truth is contrary to Goodness, and therefore to will what is contrary to Truth (ie to lie) is sinful, and an imperfection
If God willed to tell a lie, then He sinned (P -> Q)
God did not sin (not Q)
Therefore, God did not tell a lie (not P).

3 functions as a kind of lemma supporting 4, and itself is proved by 1, 2, and the law of identity. Then, once 4 is accepted, it is a simple operation of modus tollens to arrive at the conclusion that God did not (that is, never has done so) tell a lie.

Multiple refutations are possible:

Hermeneutics
To counter this particular argument I would say that the original claim is somewhat dishonest because they do not seem to quote Sarah in an honest way. He omits the Hebrew word “balah” (בָּלָה), in verse 12, which indicates that Sarah stated “I am waxed old” (KJV).
So God didn't lie later when He quotes Sarah with “Shall I in truth bear a child, old as I am?”
God doesn't quote every single thing Sarah said, which is not a lie either. Not even a lie of omission. It seems rather merciful of God to not point out how disrespectful Sarah was being.

Pure Logic #1
The answer from Jaredad7 here gives a pure logic method to disprove it.

A basic outline of the proof would be as follows

Truth is identical with Goodness
To will what is contrary to Goodness is sinful, and an imperfection
Since Truth and Goodness are identical, whatever is contrary to Truth is contrary to Goodness, and therefore to will what is contrary
to Truth (ie to lie) is sinful, and an imperfection
If God willed to tell a lie, then He sinned (P -> Q)
God did not sin (not Q)
Therefore, God did not tell a lie (not P).



Pure Logic #2

God is Omniscient
God is Immutable
God is Good
Lying/Deception is not Good.
God cannot be "not good"
Therefore God cannot lie.

This is based on the natural assumptions about God (1 through 3).

Simple, God is light and in Him there is no darkness. Lies or deceit can be equated to darkness in a lot of ways, let's use the analogy of being a guide to someone, if you lie to him that there is no ditch in his path then he is in darkness because he does not know what is in his path, similar to a person walking in darkness, he or she does not see and will stumble.
Alternatively, person who knows that a ditch is in his or her path is in light because they know, so light and knowledge go hand in hand, darkness and ignorance also go hand in hand.
if lies is a subset of spiritual darkness which can be defined as absence of light or God for God is light or truth then it holds that light or truth which dwells with God cannot co-exist with lies or darkness hence God cannot lie.
1 John 5:1

God is light, and in him is no darkness at all.




Truth
Lies




God is the Father of all truth and everything that is true
Satan is the Father of all lies and everything that is false


Associated with light in the Bible
Associated with darkness in the Bible



